# What's wrong with my web service client? 

Tags: c#, web-services

Web service is created in PHP im calling by adding a reference in C#

```
funcRequest aa = new funcRequest();
aa.param = "ZZ";          
string z;
funcResponse a = new funcResponse();
z = a.result;
```

i created like this to call the web service from C# but looks its not giving any value back .. where am i wrong ?

Comment: this code is weird on so many levels! Could you please post the complete code? Specifically the definitions of funcRequest function.

Comment: What kind of webservice do you use?

Comment: its a SOAP PHP based (nusoap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating the response object yourself. You should be doing *something* like:

```
FuncRequest request = new FuncRequest("ZZ");
MyWebService service = new MyWebService();

FuncResponse response = service.DoSomething(request);
```

Obviously the exact details will depend on how you're connecting to the service, whether you're generating the proxy code etc, but basically you need to get something involved which represents the service itself.

Comment: Thanks john .. im not getting what is MyWebService ??

Comment: @Sudantha: It's the type representing your web service. You'll probably want to get Visual Studio to build this for you - in  solution explorer, right click on your project and choose "Add Service Reference".

Comment: when i add it it comes as a namespace and inside that i have my functions so cannot create a object of it ..

Comment: @Sudantha: You're not being very clear to be honest. It will create a *type* (within a namespace). You need to create an instance of that type (as per my sample code). You can then call the methods of the service.

Comment: Thanks a lot john i got it correct  ... but service.DoSomething(request); .. .... i cannot pass a `request object` to coz it accept a string .. why is that ?

Comment: @Sudantha: Well presumably your web service is just defined to accept a string as the request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to instantiate and make requests with the generated client proxy class or something similar, you can't just new up requests and responses and in this manner, you need to *use*  and *retrieve* them, respectively. For instance, if your service reference was named `MyService` then you ought to have a `MyServiceClient` class available to you, so that:

```
using (var myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient())
{
    var request = new MyServiceRequestType();

    request.MyProperty = "zzz";

    var response = myServiceClient.MakeRequest(request);

}
```